# How to inject IHubContext in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: signalr, autofac, azure-mobile-services

To get an IHubContext from outside the hub I use:

```
public class EventSender
{
   private readonly IHubContext context;

   public EventSender(ApiServices services)
   {
       context = services.GetRealtime<MyHub>();
   }

   public void Send(string message)
   {
       context.Clients.All.Send(message);
   }
}
```

Where `services` is an `ApiServices` instance that gets injected into the calling class.
What if I want to inject the `IHubContext` itself? How do I do that? 
I tried to register the `IHubContext` instance in `WebApiConfig.cs` like this:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder(options, (httpConfig, autofac) =>
{
    autofac.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
    autofac.RegisterInstance(??).As<IHubContext>(); <-- ????
    ....
```

But this has 2 problems:

1. I don't have access to the `ApiServices` instance (and `WebApiConfig` class is static so I can't inject it there).
2. What type do I register it as? `IHubContext` seems too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can inject ApiServices, you can have access while trying to register your dependencies.

Can you try something like this?

```
autofac.Register(c => 
  {
    var services = c.Resolve<ApiServices>();
    return services.GetRealtime<MyHub>();
  }.As<IHubContext>();
```

And in your constructor:

```
public EventSender(IHubContext context)
{
  this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Great! I was wondering how can I get an instance of `ApiServices` during startup. There's still the problem of injecting the same hub context to every `IHubContext` dependency but I think this should be solved by changing the dependency to something else than `IHubContext`. Still, very valuable info!